# How to get localized bundle display names of _other_ apps

Tags: cocoa, localization, nsbundle

I am writing an app launcher on macos and want to display localized app names. The app is *not* localized, however I want the app to display localized app names. I'd like to fetch the localized app names of available bundles, however macos seems to make problems when it comes to extracting localized strings from NSBBundle objects, since the preferredLocalizations, which seems to be the root of related localization functions, seems to be the intersection of the localizations of the bundles at hand and those of the app/main bundle. How can I make an app bundle (my main bundle) mimic having every localization available on earth? This looks like the straight forward solution to my Y problem, I'd appreciate any other solution to the X problem (getting localized bundle display names) though.